# BeanCreation Exception while running SpringBoot jar file

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm creating a Spirng Securited aplication with some password encoder and user accounts. I'm having problem while running .jar file. When I run it in IDE everything works great. Seems like creation of Bean named passwordEncoder must be finished before creating userService. I don't know how to enforce such creation. Or maybe I'm wrong and the issue is something other. Here is code:

Bean:

```
  @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
```

UserService

```
 @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                       RoleRepository roleRepository,
                       BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
```

SecurityConfig

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
```

Exceprion

```
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'instalator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/suchar/Dokumenty/Java%20Training/JDict/target/JDictionary-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/micsoc/dictionary/service/UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bCryptPasswordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this in `UserService`

```
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                   RoleRepository roleRepository,
                   @Lazy BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In UserService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bean is autowired twice. Thats what you are getting the exception. Inject the dependency either via class variable or via constructor, but dont make it in both ways.
 Either
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

```
@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                   RoleRepository roleRepository,
                   BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}
```

or

@Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

```
@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                   RoleRepository roleRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
}
```

Comment: You were right. I changed UserService and it worked. I also need add @lazy addnotanion to everything woked properly. THANKS A LOT